# d3-funnel rotate funnel labels

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, rotation

I've been working with jakezatecky/d3-funnel to create a simple funnel graph.
I need to be able to rotate the the labels inside the sections.

I tried add

**.style('trasform', 'rotate(180reg)')**

to the *group.append("text")*

I've created a jsBin sample: http://jsbin.com/xafomoyume/1/edit?html,js,output

I need to flip some of the labels and other labels should be rotated 90 degrees to the right.
If I try to just rotate each font rotates and the text is distorted

Thanks in advance